# Drools high level algorithm design for billing system

Tags: architecture, drools, billing

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction to help me devise a high level algorithm to solve a problem like the one explained below, using Drools.

Let’s consider a billing system in which for a given month, and a given service, I can get from the database millions of records, like call detail records (CDR), i.e. with a client id and many other fields which I want to use to reason over in the rules. The thing is, that I do not only need to take actions based on the individual records, but also based on conditions that would apply to certain aggregations. For example, let’s say that a different price would be applied for all the CDRs after a certain threshold number was reached (that is, each CDR after the 500th is cheaper). In reality, the rules would be much more complicated than that.

Now, I am pretty sure that the idea is not to insert all these records together into the engine (KieSession) and afterwards fire all the rules. Therefore, I would need some Object, let’s call it an “accounting element”, in which I can collect all the information from each processed record. In this case I would do:

```
for each CDR loop:
    Insert a record;
    Fire all the rules;
    Delete the record;
```

And inside the Drools’ rules I would need to update my accounting object, e.g. counting the number of records processed for each client/service.

Moreover, since I am also going to be taking decisions based on this accounting object, it will also have to be inserted in the KieSession, and remain there through the whole session, right?

I appreciate any advice you can give me regarding possible solution/implementation approaches to such a problem using Drools, and please do tell me if what I said makes sense or correct me if it doesn’t. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much in your question, and so there isn't much that can be wrong.

Only a few remarks:

1. Alternating insert and fireAllRules one by one may not be optimal. Be prepared to have batch size N as a parameter.
2. The rule engine is CPU bound, fetching CDRs is i/o bound. The usual principles apply here if minimising elapsed time is important.
3. It may be advantageous to process CDRs sorted by clients. A stable sort (maintaining date/time order) can be run independently.
4. There may be (or come up in the future) *client groups* that have to be monitored as a whole. Only a variant for the sort criteria.